# fcntl F_GETLK always returns F_UNLCK

Tags: c, macos, file-locking, fcntl

I am trying to understand POSIX file-region locks in C. The program below is really simple, sets the lock to F_WRLCK and then gets locks. There is no errors during opening/setting lock. Unfortunatelly it's always returning F_UNLCK. Where is the mistake ? Is it possible that it doesnt work on OSX correctly ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
void printLockType(int lock) {
    if ( lock == F_RDLCK ) {
            printf("readlock %i \n", lock);
    }else if ( lock == F_WRLCK ) {
            printf("writelock %i \n", lock);
    }else if ( lock == F_UNLCK ) {
            printf("unlock %i \n", lock);
    } else {
            printf("other %i\n", lock);
    }
} 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{    
    int fd;
    struct flock fl ,fl2;

    fl2.l_type   = F_RDLCK;  /* read/write lock */
    fl2.l_whence = 0; /* beginning of file */
    fl2.l_start  = 0;        /* offset from l_whence */
    fl2.l_len    = 100;        /* length, 0 = to EOF */
    fl2.l_pid    = getpid();

    fl.l_type   = F_WRLCK;  /* read/write lock */
    fl.l_whence = 0; /* beginning of file */
    fl.l_start  = 0;        /* offset from l_whence */
    fl.l_len    = 1000;        /* length, 0 = to EOF */
    fl.l_pid    = getpid();

    if ((fd = open("xxx", O_RDWR)) == -1) {
        perror("open");
        exit(1);
    }


    if (fcntl(fd, F_SETLK, &fl) == -1) {
        perror("fcntl");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(fcntl(fd, F_GETLK, &fl2) == -1) {
        printf("%s \n", strerror(errno));
    } else {
        printLockType(fl2.l_type);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just a clarification: The "locks" you're talking about are not part of C but is defined by [the POSIX standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the `F_GETLK` query. It returns `F_UNLCK` when *nothing blocks the calling process from placing a lock of the given type at the given position.*

Since the calling process is the one that created these existing locks, it can also create this new lock.

---

The [Mac OS X manuals](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/fcntl.2.html) say

> ```
>  F_GETLK
> ```
>
> Get the first lock that blocks the lock description pointed to by the third argument, arg,
>               taken as a pointer to a struct flock (see above).  The information retrieved overwrites the
>               information passed to fcntl in the flock structure. **If no lock is found that would prevent
>               this lock from being created, the structure is left unchanged by this function call except
>               for the lock type which is set to `F_UNLCK`**.